# GAM - setting K-values before or after testing the different models

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines, smoothing, ecology

I'm working with GAM and I'm testing different models with and without certain variables, and I need to set k-values for the different smoothers. Do I need to use the exact same k-values prior to testing the models, and if so does the results from gam.check() for all the models have non-significant p-values? Or can the models have different k-values based on the gam.check() results and then test the models - even though the k-values are not the same within the same smoothers?

Answer (score 2):

I think I would set the `k` for a particular covariate to the largest value of `k` identified by `k.check()` over the set of models in which that covariate participated.

As to whether the results of the basis dimension test all need to be non-significant, that's trickier to answer. You shouldn't ignore rejections of the null hypothesis that the basis was sufficiently large. You can do other things to test, such as plotting the deviance residuals against the covariate and then fit a model (`family = gaussian()`) with the deviance residuals as the response and a single smooth of the covariate of interest, where you set `k` to be **larger** (say twice as large) as the `k` used in the model you are checking.

One reason for the null hypothesis to be rejected in the heuristic test of the basis dimension is unmodelled temporal or spatial dependence; if that's a possibility for your data/setting, then look into that.

Also, unless I had very good reason to leave some covariates out of the model, I would just fit the full model with all the covariates needed and then use `select = TRUE` and appropriately sized values of `k` for each covariate/smooth term. Especially so if the reason for the models with and without covariates was part of a manual model selection process...